# DFS difference between graph and tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I was trying to understand DFS algorithm for graphs in general and trees to be specific. I noticed the order of nodes be printed out is different for graphs and trees.

In Graphs, we print the parent node and then the child node.

```
void Graph::DFS(int v)
{   
    // Mark the current node as visited and print it
    visited[v] = true;
    cout << v << " ";

    // Recur for all the vertices adjacent to this vertex
    vector<int>::iterator i;
    for (i = adj[v].begin(); i != adj[v].end(); ++i)
    if (!visited[*i])
        DFS(*i);

}
```

In trees, we print the child node first then the parent node

```
void DFS(struct node *head)
{
    if (head)
    {
        if (head->left)
        {
            DFS(head->left);
        }
        if (head->right)
        {
            DFS(head->right);
        }
        printf("%d  ", head->a);
    }
}
```

I would like to know why the ordering is different between the two. Should it be the same? I think my understanding of the algorithm is wrong. Can someone please correct me on this?

Answer (score 2):

There are two variations when traversing the nodes in a graph: pre-order and post-order. In binary trees, there is another option: in-order. There are the differences:

1. **Pre-order**: Current node is processed *before* processing it's neighbours / children.
2. **Post-order**: Current node is processed *after* processing it's neighbours / children.
3. **In-order**: Only applicable to binary trees. First, left child is processed, then current node and lastly right child.

Different variations are useful in different cases, for example traversing a [BST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) in-order will give it's elements in order.

Answer (score 1):

Those are two variations of DFS: pre-order and post-order. Both are valid; which one you use depends on the problem you are trying to solve.

You just happened to find a post-order tree traverse and a pre-order graph traverse. It could just as well have gone the other way.